# page not getting forwarded through createRenderUrl

Tags: javascript, liferay

I am a newbie to liferay..what I want to do is to pass value to javascript function on click of a link and call another jsp page from that function with the value passed to that function..

Here is what I tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendId(userid) {
    AUI().ready("liferay-portlet-url", function(A) {
       var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();

       alert("in function"+userid);

       portletURL.setParameter("jspPage", "/html/assignsites/assignSites.jsp" );
       portletURL.setParameter("id", userid);
       portletURL.setPortletId("assignsites_WAR_AssignSitesportlet");

    });    }
</script>

for (User usersList: users) {   

%>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="sendId('<%=usersList.getUserId()%>');"><%=usersList.getFullName()%></a></td>
        <td><%=usersList.getEmailAddress()%></td>
    </tr>
<%
}
%>
```

I want to retrieve the userId on assignSites.jsp so i am setting that value in portletURL.
But when I click the link alert gets showed up and nothing happens..am I doing it right..?

Please someone guide me.

Comment: there is nothing written in js code that make something to happen.

Comment: Iam setting the url to which I want to forward in portletUrl ..I thought by doing so it will forward to the desired page..can you please correct my code on what i need to perform?

Comment: I also tried modifying the javascript code by adding portletId and making the AUI().use() to AUI.action() still nothing happens

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="sendId('<%=usersList.getUserId()%>');"><%=usersList.getFullName()%></a>`
Instead of above, can you use this code
`<a href='<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/assignsites/assignSites.jsp"/><portlet:param name="id" value="<%=usersList.getUserId()%>"/></portlet:renderURL>' onclick="sendId('<%=usersList.getUserId()%>');"><%=usersList.getFullName()%></a>`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the code you provide:

- AUI namespaces are meant to be top-level, not parts of the implementation of a function.
- Despite this, you're not doing anything with the constructed portletURL variable.

Pankaj Kathiriya's comment already gives a way to generate the URLs without any javascript involved at all, here's a pretty-printed (and slightly changed) version of it: (Warning: Pseudocode, written here and never tested)

```
for (User usersList: users) {   
%>
    <portlet:renderURL var="assignSiteURL">
       <portlet:param name="id" value="<%=usersList.getUserId()%>"/>
       <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/assignsites/assignSites.jsp"/>
    </portletRenderURL>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<%=assignSiteURL%>"><%=usersList.getFullName()%></a></td>
        <td><%=usersList.getEmailAddress()%></td>
    </tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Keep in mind that AUI namespaces are meant to isolate your JS code from the code of other portlets: Your proposed code would end up with a global function called sendId(x) - any other portlet on the same page could introduce just another method with the same name. This would result in a conflict that can be hard to resolve, thus you shouldn't do this.

Of course, the drawback of this isolation is that you can't just call such methods as easily in "onclick" handlers. However, you can enumerate all nodes that you want to change and dynamically update them.

If you insist on the javascript solution, I leave this for you (or somebody else), partly because I don't expect it to be necessary in this case.